# Installing a Drupal template

Tags: drupal

My client had a Drupal project. She wanted me to install it in my system and develop it further. I downloaded that template, copied it to `var\www\html` folder, gave suitable file permissions and opened it in browser. And I got this error:

```
Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error message
PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/html/csp-v1/includes/lock.inc).
```

Where should I give my `MySQL` password?

Answer (score 2):

In the settings.php file. You can configure your database information.

sites/default/settings.php

```css
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'drupal',
      'username' => 'drupal',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I did it, but it has a port: 3306. So when I redirect it to `http://localhost:3306/csp-v1/`, I get a mixture of ASCII characters like this: 
`[���
5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1�`���|CuF<;Rl�ÿ÷�€����������JiUL\i{P\]Aj�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order`

Comment: This seems like you loose file encoding. If you have some special chars not supported by basic ascii set (umlauts or something) you should use UTF8 NO BOM encoding.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you talking about Drupal template (file) or about Drupal theme? Those are 2 different things. Theme defines how you Drupal site will look like and template is just a single file in a theme, one of many, defining just a part of some page or similar.

So, not even theme (not to mention single template file) is enough to have full Drupal site.

If you have whole site, change the database access info, as Tchevass explained, the login and go to Configuration -> Media -> File system and check are all paths writable, because Drupal needs them. Just click "Save configuration" and if some field get's red outline that means path is not writable...so you have to make it.

But if you have only a theme you have to download and install Drupal, then move your theme to /sites/all/themes/theme_name and go to Appearance and turn it on.

Comment: Actually it isn't a Template/Theme. It is a drupal project. I downloaded it and tried to install it, but it is returning errors